# Check number of visits via link

Tags: support, feature-request

If I share a link, can I check, how many times site has been shown via that link?
I only see 'milestones' (ak. [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster)), but can I check if link was visited *78* times or just *26*?

If it isn't possible, maybe it would be good feature?

Edit: In order to avoid any doubt, this question is equivalent to question about progress in publicist badges like [Announcer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer). I was thinking it was clear, but as @A.L pointed out, maybe it wasn't.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible but I agree that it would be a nice feature.

Comment: sorry my comment was ambiguous... It certainly should be *possible*, I'm just trying to say I don't think there's a way to see it at the moment with the current Stack Overflow user interface.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Och, I misunderstood. I deleted my comment. There is no point to keep him here. However, maybe on the badge site? Maybe when hover the mouse over a date? I believe, it is possible to find a solution.

Comment: See also: [View progress towards Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/262755)

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This assumes I've understood the data correctly. I can be wrong.

There's no way to check this using a fancy GUI, or in real-time. However, thanks to [GDPR requests](//stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request), we now get a data dump with this data. Specifically, the file named `qa/<SE site>/PostReferralsOutbound.json` contains this info, including links that haven't made it to various badges yet. Specifically, it includes the post ID, and the count. From what I can tell, `PostReferralsInbound.json` lists the links you've clicked (so if you click a URL with a user ID in it, it'll be recorded there. `PostReferralsOutbound.json` covers your shares).

There's actually one thing I noticed while processing some of this data though - and I'm not entirely sure if it matters, or if it's a system bug, but I have [9 announcer badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=6296561). I filtered the JSON using Python, and it gave me 8:

```
[    {
        "postId":272165,
        "count":26,
        "first":"2019-01-18T12:07:37.637Z",
        "last":"2020-04-23T09:03:46.940Z"

},
    {
        "postId":254995,
        "count":51,
        "first":"2019-02-28T06:11:30.853Z",
        "last":"2020-04-21T19:51:48.007Z"

},
    {
        "postId":386505,
        "count":87,
        "first":"2019-06-28T09:22:18.793Z",
        "last":"2019-12-20T13:32:18.467Z"

},
    {
        "postId":386324,
        "count":30,
        "first":"2019-06-29T10:24:00.107Z",
        "last":"2019-10-14T18:20:08.233Z"

},
    {
        "postId":385023,
        "count":49,
        "first":"2019-07-02T14:19:11.377Z",
        "last":"2019-12-09T02:34:36.513Z"

},
    {
        "postId":386562,
        "count":69,
        "first":"2019-07-11T20:58:22.930Z",
        "last":"2020-02-18T00:03:11.280Z"

},
    {
        "postId":387546,
        "count":69,
        "first":"2019-09-13T20:02:26.330Z",
        "last":"2020-01-02T21:59:54.710Z"

},
    {
        "postId":389908,
        "count":244,
        "first":"2019-09-29T20:53:38.610Z",
        "last":"2019-12-16T13:58:56.810Z"

}
]
```

The one it's missing is this one:

```
{"postId":389942,"count":20,"first":"2019-10-02T07:55:46.477Z","last":"2020-01-08T04:32:04.910Z"},
```

Which only reports 20, but I still got a badge for it. Could be a bug with the awarding at the time, could've been adjusted after, could've been a bug with reporting/storing, or the data is wrong/not what I think it is. This is just speculation, and probably only an employee can answer that accurately. I cannot guarantee the accuracy of the data, but it at least got the other ones correct, so I'll trust that the data is updated.

The point being: yes, you should be able to get at least an approximation in visits on links by using the GDPR request. The data is somewhat hard to extract though, because the data is on a per-site basis. Looking at qa/meta.stackoverflow.com only reveals links to posts on meta.stackoverflow.com, and not on stackoverflow.com or some other SE site.