# Shared post statistics and view count

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow has a nice feature to share a post, which attaches the user id into the question URL. For example:

[Difference between Include, Extends, Use, Macro, Embed in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526990/difference-between-include-extends-use-macro-embed-in-twig)

```
[share] edit close delete flag
```

According to the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) help page, under the **Other Badges** section:

- **Announcer:** Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses
- **Booster:** Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses
- **Publicist:** Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

**Question:**

How can I check my sharing statistic and progress?

Is this featured already implemented? I searched a lot to no avail.

**Update:**

[A similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311206/how-do-i-check-how-close-i-am-to-win-announcer-booster-or-publicist-badge) has been asked 4.5 years ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check how close I am to win Announcer, Booster or Publicist badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311206/how-do-i-check-how-close-i-am-to-win-announcer-booster-or-publicist-badge)

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280429/check-number-of-visits-via-link, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352172/how-to-track-announcer-badge-progression, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299596/can-i-find-out-how-i-got-an-announcer-badge, and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges makes a circle of duplicates it looks like.